# Is it possible to migrate existing data (Like in Prometheus and elk )to datadog?

Tags: datadog

Is it possible to migrate existing data (Like in Prometheus and elk )to datadog?

There is a setup for live streaming of Prometheus metrics to Datadog by configuring datadog config. But what could be done with the past data?

Answer (score 1):

You mostly have to wait for it all to fill in over time.

> Metric timestamps cannot be more than 10 minutes in the future or more than 1 hour in the past.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/